# jQuery case insensitive contains selector - 1.8.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

I'm having trouble implementing this. From other questions I have the following snippet:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = jQuery.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return jQuery(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

But I get the error: `TypeError: jQuery.expr.createPseudo is not a function`

Any ideas? In addition, where should this snippet be placed? Document ready?

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: Are you sure that you are using jQuery 1.8.1? Perhaps jQuery is being loaded twice, and and older jQuery is overriding the first one.

You can check by opening the Javascript console and checking the output of

    jQuery().jquery

Comment: Ah :/ There was an older version on the page, removing this and ensuring the latest is there now gives me: `TypeError: $ is not a function` ??

Comment: If there were indeed multiple versions of jQuery on the page, perhaps it was initially intentional. Check for the presence of ".noConflict()", which unbinds $ in anticipation of its being re-used by other libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `createPseudo`:

```
jQuery.expr[":"].Contains = function(obj,index,meta) {
    return jQuery(obj).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(meta[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

From [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/jquery-custom-selectors-with-parameters.html).
It doesn't matter where you put this - you're just defining a function, not accessing the DOM - so it doesn't *have* to be inside `document.ready`. Just make sure you load jQuery before you define this filter and define it before you use it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why wouldn't he use createPseudo? isn't createPseudo the preferred method for creating pseudo-selectors, to ensure future compatibility?

Comment: I agree with Will but tried this nevertheless: I get an error, 'Shoo' was my search query `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Contains("shoo")`